# Optimization of custom rank function in C#

Tags: c#

I have written a code for students class to **Rank** them according to their marks. The code works accurately and gives the result as

```
Name:B  Marks:30    Rank:1
Name:C  Marks:30    Rank:1
Name:A  Marks:20    Rank:3
Name:D  Marks:10    Rank:4
```

But I need it to be optimized so it wont take too much of time to be processed. Below is the code

```
public List<Students> GetRanks(List<Students> students)
{
    List<Students> rStudents = new List<Students>();
    students = students.OrderByDescending(a => a.marks).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < students.Count; i++)
    {
        Students stu = new Students();
        stu.Id = students[i].Id;
        stu.Name = students[i].Name;
        stu.marks = students[i].marks;

        if (i > 0 && students[i].marks == students[i - 1].marks)
        {
            stu.rank = rStudents.Select(a => a.rank).LastOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            stu.rank = i + 1;
        }
        rStudents.Add(stu);
    }
    return rStudents;
}

List<Students> students = new List<Students>() {
new Students() { Id = 1, Name = "A", marks = 20 },
new Students() { Id = 1, Name = "B", marks = 30 },
new Students() { Id = 1, Name = "C", marks = 30 },
new Students() { Id = 1, Name = "D", marks = 10 },
};

List<Students> rStudents = GetRanks(students);
            
            
public class Students
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double marks { get; set; }
    public int rank { get; set; }
}


foreach (Students s in GetRanks(students))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Name:{s.Name}\tMarks:{s.marks}\tRank:{s.rank}");
}
```

Comment: "But I need it to be optimized" then I would suggest to migrate the question to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) StackOverflow is not the right platform for such questions

Comment: Ok, I'll post it on Code Review. Thanks

Comment: This is going to scan the list each time; `rStudents.Select(a => a.rank).LastOrDefault();`. Just keep track of the rank in a new variable. Why are you creating new `Students` instances?

Comment: Are you getting Student List from the database?

Comment: what is the purpose of foor loop if you are just ordering it using the Orderbydescending method

Comment: Hi @JeremyLakeman would this help?
`
List<Students> rStudents = new List<Students>();
 students = students.OrderByDescending(a => a.marks).ToList();
 for (int i = 0; i < students.Count; i++)
 {
  int rnk = i > 0 && students[i].marks == students[i - 1].marks ? rStudents[i - 1].rank : i + 1;

  rStudents.Add(new Students()
  {
   Id = students[i].Id,
   Name = students[i].Name,
   marks = students[i].marks,
   rank = rnk
  });

 }
 return rStudents;
`

Comment: @MukeshVadodariya, yes I am getting list from DB

Comment: @zetawars, for loop was to rank the students using 'I' as variable

Comment: @SwapnilWalunj, please check my answer and accept if looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be pretty darn fast:

```
var rank = 1;
students
    .GroupBy(x => x.marks)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(xs =>
    {
        xs.ToList().ForEach(x => x.rank = rank);
        rank += xs.Count();
    });
```

With your sample data I get:

[image: students]

Here's a non-destructive version of the code:

```
public static List<Students> GetRanks(List<Students> students)
{
    var rank = 1;
    return
        students
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.marks)
            .GroupBy(x => x.marks)
            .SelectMany(xs =>
            {
                var r = rank;
                rank += xs.Count();
                return xs.Select(x => new Students()
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    Name = x.Name,
                    marks = x.marks,
                    rank = r,
                });
            })
            .ToList();
}
```

I measured this using 100_000 randomly created students. My code completed in 110 milliseconds. The original code in the question took 64_119 milliseconds.

Yes, this code was nearly 600x faster.

Answer (score 2):

Remove unnecessary resource.and using **yield** will have performance impact in large data. Fewer line and more readable.
If you are fetching data from **DataBase** it's better idea sort them there then fetch them.

```
  public static IEnumerable<Students> GetRanks(List<Students> students)
  {
      List<Students> rStudents = students.OrderByDescending(a => a.marks).ToList();
      for (int i = 0; i < rStudents.Count; i++)
      {
        if (i > 0 && rStudents[i].marks == rStudents[i - 1].marks)
          {
              rStudents[i].rank = rStudents[i - 1].rank;
          }
          else
          {
              rStudents[i].rank = i + 1;
          }
          yield return rStudents[i];
      }
  }
```

Comment: Exactly the code I worked out myself. Guess we're up with the same speeds then ;)

Answer (score -1):

More then 50% improvement if have large collect with a new method called **GetRanksV1**

```
namespace StudentPerformance
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            List<Students> students = new List<Students>();
            Random _random = new Random();
            for (int i = 1; i < 10001; i++)
            {
                students.Add(new Students() { Id = i, Name = "A" + i, marks = _random.Next(10, 50) });
            }
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var tmp = GetRanks(students);
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Execution Time: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
            watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var tmp1 = GetRanksV1(students);
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Execution Time V1: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
            foreach (Students s in tmp1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Name:{s.Name}\tMarks:{s.marks}\tRank:{s.rank}");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static List<Students> GetRanks(List<Students> students)
        {
            List<Students> rStudents = new List<Students>();
            students = students.OrderByDescending(a => a.marks).ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < students.Count; i++)
            {
                Students stu = new Students();
                stu.Id = students[i].Id;
                stu.Name = students[i].Name;
                stu.marks = students[i].marks;

                if (i > 0 && students[i].marks == students[i - 1].marks)
                {
                    stu.rank = rStudents.Select(a => a.rank).LastOrDefault();
                }
                else
                {
                    stu.rank = i + 1;
                }
                rStudents.Add(stu);
            }
            return rStudents;
        }
        public static List<Students> GetRanksV1(List<Students> students)
        {
            int Srno = 0;
            var tmp = students.GroupBy(a => a.marks).OrderByDescending(o => o.Key).Select(s => new { Mark = s.Key, Rand = ++Srno, });
            var values = from s in students
                         join t in tmp on s.marks equals t.Mark
                         select new Students { Id = s.Id, Name = s.Name, marks = s.marks, rank = t.Rand };
            return values.ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Students
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double marks { get; set; }
        public int rank { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Mukesh Vadodariya,
Execution time changed drastically and saved the time. Thanks
Execution Time: 4612 ms
Execution Time V1: 32 ms

Comment: Hi @Mukesh Vadodariya, there is 1 issue that still persist is ranking system, if 2 people gets rank 1, then next rank will be 3. That was the main reason for me using for loop.

Comment: @SwapnilWalunj Looking into it.

Comment: @MukeshVadodariya - You code is simply incrementing `rank` by one each time. It should be incrementing it by the number of students on the previous `rank`.